# How to stop progress bar from filling to 100% every calculation?

Tags: javascript

I am currently making a progress bar for my application and I am facing a problem with every entry in a list, the progress bar fills 100%, then chances back to the actual progress (for example 34% if 34/100 calculations done).

I would like it to just show the actual progress.

Here is the code:

```js
function readLines() {

    let progress = 0;
    let percentage = 0;
    const file = document.getElementById("fileList").value;

    fetch(`/application/${file}/lines`, {

        method: 'GET'

    }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {

            const keys = Object.keys(data)
            let html = `<tr><th>Word</th><th>Occurrence</th></tr>`;

            const progressBar = document.getElementById("progress-bar");
            const updateButton = document.getElementById("fileList");

            function updateProgressBar(progress) {

                progressBar.innerHTML = "<div id='loading-bar'></div>";
                const progressBarFill = document.getElementById("loading-bar");
                progressBarFill.style.width = `${progress}%`;

            }

            keys.forEach(key => {

                updateButton.addEventListener("change", function () {

                    progress += 1;
                    const length = Object.keys(data).length;
                    percentage = (progress / length) * 100;

                    updateProgressBar(percentage);

                })

                if (key.substring(0, 1) !== "1") {

                    html += `<tr><td>${key}</td><td>${data[key]}</td></tr>`

                } else {

                    html += `<tr><td>${key}</td><td>${data[key]}</td></tr>`

                }

            })

            document.getElementById("showTable").innerHTML = html;

            percentage = 0;

        });

}
```

Comment: For each key in `data`, you add another event listener to  `updateButton`. Thus `updateProgressBar` gets called for each key in `data` whenever the change event is triggered on `updateButton`. I would define your functions (`updateProgressBar`, the event listener) once, then call them every time you need them.

Comment: It's not immediately clear from your code what you're trying to do. Why does a button have a `change` event? If it's a singular element element why are you constantly attaching an event to it? It may help you to add some relevant markup to your question as a [mcve] using the snippet tool `[<>]` to better help your case. Note: there is an actual [`<progress>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress) element that you might consider.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try changing these lines of code

```
progressBar.innerHTML = "<div id='loading-bar'></div>";
const progressBarFill = document.getElementById("loading-bar");
progressBarFill.style.width = `${progress}%`;
```

to just

```
progressBar.innerHTML = '<div id="loading-bar" style="width:`${progress}%`"></div>";
```

This way you directly create the bar with the correct width instead of creating it with a 100% width and then reducing it

Comment: Either I am doing something wrong or that line of code doesn't work. The bar now goes and stays at 100%.